# Loop through Multi-Dimensional Array and Print

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array that I would like to pull certain information from and output it using php/html (i.e. game, id, rating). I have the basics down, although I only get the information from the first array in the output. I know that looping is what I need to do, although I'm not exactly sure how to return more than one record at a time. Some of the information that is in one array may not be in the other, as you can see there is no [info] in the first one.

Here's my code:

```
<?php

$review = $developer->api('/source');

    function d($d){
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($d);
        echo '</pre>';
    }

    d($review[data][0][game]);
    d($review[data][0][game][rating]);
?>
```

This is the output:

```
Array( [data] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 2010_1110 [from] => Array ( [name] => Pebkac [id] => 11001010  ) [game] => Array ( [id] => 2112 [name] => New Game [rating] => Array ( [action] => 9 [graphics] => 10 ) ) [comments] => Array ( [data] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 2010_1111 [from] => Array ( [name] => My Friend  [id] => 10100110 ) [message] => hi there. [created_time] => 8:00 P.M. ) ) ) ) ) 

[paging] => Array ( [previous] => url1 [next] => url2 ))

Array( [data] => Array ( [1] => Array ( [id] => 2010_1112 [from] => Array ( [name] => Pebkac [id] => 11001010  ) [game] => Array ( [id] => 5050 [name] => Another Game [rating] => Array ( [action] => 8 [graphics] => 8 ) ) [info] => [created_time] => 8:59 P.M. [owns] => Array ( [data] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 20100112   [name] => Friend Two ) ) ) [comments] => Array ( [data] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 2010_1113 [from] => Array ( [name] => My Friend  [id] => 10100110 ) [message] => hi there. [created_time] => 9:00 P.M. ) ) ) ) )
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16141590/printing-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-table-using-for-loop

Answer (score 4):

Depending on what you want to do, you can either do a nested for loop or if you have n number of dimensions, you can recursively call your function until the result is no longer an array. Something like this:

```
function printNode($node) {
    foreach ($node as $nodeKey => $nodeValue) {
        if (is_array($nodeValue)) {
            printNode($nodeValue);
        } else {
            print $nodeValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I put your code in there and it outputs everything all jammed together. How can I specify just one or two things to pull out and print? Thanks!

Comment: @Larry Pebkac: You can check `$nodeValue` if it matches one of the keys you want to print.

Comment: I tried: if (array_key_exists('name', $review)) { echo "Found"; } - and it comes up empty. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @Larry Pebkac: Once $nodeValue is in the 'else' block, we know it is NOT any array, so array_key_exists will not work. We are recursing through the multi-dimentional array (i.e. we are calling our own function in the 'if' block), so we have a scalar value once we reach the 'else' block, so you can just use a simple equals operator, like if ($nodeValue == 'name') print $nodeValue. If you will only ever want to print name values, you can even change the 'else' into an 'else if' with the condition above.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, all you need is a `foreach` loop and it has nothing to do with multi-dimensionality.

Comment: Yes, but please look at the raw output of the array - it's a multidimensional array that I need to loop through, and I'm asking how to do it. Thanks!