# Printing a multi dimensional array in table using For loop

Tags: php, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I want to Print a multidimensional array in table using For loop only.
This is `$myArray`

```
$myArray =    Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 598
        [1] => Introducing abc
        [2] => 
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 596
        [1] => Big Things Happening at abc
        [2] => 
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 595
        [1] => Should I send abc?
        [2] => 
    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 586
        [1] => Things you need to know about abc :P
       [2] => 
    )
```

);

update a new array as `var_dump($myArray );`

Comment: Have a look at all those questions SO shows on the right as "related", for example [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142426/loop-through-multi-dimensional-array-and-print?rq=1). Are you really sure there is nothing in there that will do what you want?

Comment: No they couldn't help me.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There's a tonne of different approaches to this, so why not have some fun with it.

### If you MUST use a for loop

No idea why you would, unless it's for a school assignment:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++) {
  echo('<tr>');
  echo('<td>' . $data[$i][0] . '</td>');
  echo('<td>' . $data[$i][1] . '</td>');
  echo('<td>' . $data[$i][2] . '</td>');
  echo('</tr>');
}
```

But then that's kinda stupid directly accessing the ID's, lets use another for loop in the row:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++) {
  echo('<tr>');
  for($j=0;$j<count($data[$i]);$j++) {
    echo('<td>' . $data[$i][$j] . '</td>');
  } 
  echo('</tr>');
}
```

### Replace it with an equally as boring foreach loop:

```
<table>
<?php foreach($items as $row) {
  echo('<tr>');
  foreach($row as $cell) {
    echo('<td>' . $cell . '</td>');
  }
  echo('</tr>');
} ?>
</table>
```

### Why not implode the array:

```
<table>
<?php foreach($items as $row) {
  echo('<tr>');
  echo('<td>');
  echo(implode('</td><td>', $row);
  echo('</td>');
  echo('</tr>');
} ?>
</table>
```

### Mix it up, screw the foreach, and go for a walk; and implode stuff along the way:

```
<?php
function print_row(&$item) {
  echo('<tr>');
  echo('<td>');
  echo(implode('</td><td>', $item);
  echo('</td>');
  echo('</tr>');
}
?>

<table>
  <?php array_walk($data, 'print_row');?>
</table>
```

### Double walking... OMG

Yeah, it looks a little silly now, but when you grow the table and things get more complex, things are a little better broken out and modularized:

```
<?php
function print_row(&$item) {
  echo('<tr>');
  array_walk($item, 'print_cell');
  echo('</tr>');
}

function print_cell(&$item) {
  echo('<td>');
  echo($item);
  echo('</td>');
}
?>

<table>
  <?php array_walk($data, 'print_row');?>
</table>
```

Comment: @duellsy Sometimes is very importante (and good!) to get to the basics! Thank you; I was completely forget about this. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Use this, which are actually two nested `for` loops:

```
print('<table>');
for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    print('<tr>');
    for($ii = 0; $ii < count($array[$i]); $ii++) {
        print("<td>{$array[$i][$ii]}</td>");
    }
    print('</tr>');
}
print('</table>');
```

Comment: this doesn't create a table as he wanted.

Comment: @Zim84 Thanks for your comment. You are right, the op mentioned it in the headline of the question. Check my update. Now it does output a html table

Comment: Used your method but table show empty like this `
<table><tr><td>
</td></tr></table>`

Comment: Then there is something wrong with your array. I've triple checked the code. can you post a recent `var_dump($array);` ?

Comment: Hi hek2mgl, I update array code using `var_dump()`, please see this, what is happen,

Answer (score 3):

Do like this

```
echo "<table>";
for($i=0;$i<count($your_array);$i++) {
     echo "<tr><td>".$your_array[$i][0]."</td>";
     echo "<td>".$your_array[$i][1]."</td>";
     echo "<td>".$your_array[$i][2]."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Hi Yogesh,
I used your method but not show data and show table as `<table><tr><td>
</td><td> </td><td> </td></tr></table>`

Comment: @ShahzadThathal So how do you want the table? You can edit this code as you want your output. It's quit simple to do.

Answer (score 3):

```
echo '<table>';
for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++) {
 echo '<tr><td>'.$array[$i][0].'</td>';
 echo '<tr><td>'.$array[$i][1].'</td>';
 echo '<tr><td>'.$array[$i][2].'</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Hi Sudo Reboot, I used your method but not show data and show table empty as `<table><tr><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td></tr></table>`

Answer (score 2):

Do this

```
$arr as your array
```

then

```
echo "<table>";
for($i = 0; $i<count($arr); $i++)
{


    echo '<tr><td>'.$arr[$i][0].'</td>';
    echo '<tr><td>'.$arr[$i][1].'</td>';
    echo '<tr><td>'.$arr[$i][2].'</td></tr>';
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: this doesn't create a table as he wanted.

Comment: @Zim84 sorry aboout that i did not read question properly. Here is my updated answer